# SUM of IndexMatch - Excel

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file with 2 tabs.
In the 1st tab `Match Results` I have all the tennis matches results form 2015 and 2016.

Example of Match Results Tab:

[image: Match Results Tab]

In the 2nd tab `Players` I'm running my analytics based on information in the `Match Results` tab.

[image: Players Tab]

In the `Match Results` tab most players have multiple entries as each player plays normally more than 1 game during the season.

In my `Players` tab, where I run my analytics, each player appears only once.

What I want to achieve is to find out the avarage number of games that a player is playing in the first Set of the total amount of tennis matches that he played. Regardless if the player is winning or losing the match.

The amount of games played in the 1st set are in `column T` of the `Match Results` tab.

The Winner of the match is in `column K`of the `Match Results` tab, the loser of the match in `column L` of the `Match Results` tab

I've been playing around with IndexMatch, but I'm only getting the first total of number of games that are played in the match.

For example;
When I search for "Duckworth J. (Column K2, `Match Results` tab), I'm only getting as result the number `8`, which are the number of games played in the 1 set of the 1st match of the season that "Duckworth J." played.

In this case I know that "Duckworth J." played 17 matches in 2015/2016.
So I first want to find the total amount of games that "Duckworht J." played during the 2015 and 2016 season. Than I want the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((K4:L50="Donald")*T4:T50)/COUNTIF(K4:L50;"Donald")
```

^^ Will sum all "Donald" scores and devide by number of rows (that Donald is mentioned).

Edit: correct now? See now that I's K and L column I should have been looking at too.

Edit 2: to save your "Best of" column we need to use sumifs(). Below is the code to get "best of 3", note the last part of sumifs() `J4:J50;3` where 3 is best of **3**.

```
=SUMIFS(T4:T50;K4:L50;"Donald";J4:J50;3)/COUNTIF(K4:L50;"Donald")
```

Comment: Hi Andreas, thank you for your answer but you're looking in the wrong tab. I need to get all the values of column T for each player.

Comment: @Wouter ok, sorry. Edited

Comment: It works now :) I was selecting the total colums instead of the rows. Thank you very much!

Comment: how do I add more requirement? For example I also want to filter on the column "Best of". Now I'm getting the total numbers of games, but I want only for the "Best of 3"

Comment: @Wouter, not sure what you mean. You mean you want to add a new column with "placement" (/position)? How do you want to select that? Isn't that just most wins?

Comment: at this moment I'm getting the total amount of games, No matter if the tennis match is a best of 3 or a best of 5 sets. What I would like is that I can only get the total amount of games played(as I have now) but only for the matches that are best of 3. So I need an extra filter

Comment: @Wouter so you mean in match result tab count win/loss on the last three or five games to know what "shape" the player is in?

Comment: No, I column J of the first tab you have the "Best Of" column. There're only 2 posibilities in that column. 3 or 5. If I use the formula above I get all the results for 3 AND 5 in column J. But I would like to get the results only from the rows who have 3 in in column J

Comment: @Wouter sorry had to eat dinner. I updated the answer again.

Comment: I'd say your data analyzing is so advanced that I think you could use a pivot table to help you. Have you used one? They may seem hard to use at first glance but once you get the hang of it, you can make wonders.

Comment: @Wouter Sorry I see that I have C1:C4 left in the formula and that is from my testing here. That should be T4:T50

Comment: @Wouter No problem